# Center Background Image of a Bootstrap Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-attachment

I want put the background image of my second Bootstrap column in the center of the column. However, right now, it is in the center of the whole view and not at the center of the column.

Here are my codes:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid cust-main-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <!-- [..] -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 bg">
      <!-- [..] -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    height: 100%;
} //In my actual code, * is html, body

.cust-main-container,
.cust-main-container > .row {
    height: 100%;
}

.bg{
    background: url('http://placehold.it/150x350');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
}

.col-sm-2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.col-sm-10 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1m8ua78z/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The background image is **fixed** (`background-attachment: fixed;`) so it's centering in the viewport instead of the column.

The width of `col-*-2` is `16.6666%`, and the width `col-*-10` is `83.3333%`. Therefore, the position of the .bg needs to be: `16.6666%+(83.3333%/2)` *or*...

`background-position: 58.33325% center;`

Because of responsiveness, you'd only want to apply this before the cols stack vertically on smaller screens..

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .bg{
        background-position: 58.33325% center;
    }
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/5GG6v3rkZ3

Answer (score 2):

You have set `background-attachment: fixed;` - remove that and set it as `background-attachment: scroll;`

With fixed "the background is fixed with regard to the viewport", see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp - hence the effect that you got.

A working sample fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/robertjakobson/4ya7pyr5/4/ (I set the background on a div inside the column as a best practice)

Answer (score -1):

Try declaring background-position: 50% 50% or just declare background-position:center